# How can we simulate webflux client (reactive) using Apache JMeter

Tags: jmeter, spring-webflux, performance-testing

I cannot find any option for Headers to use application/x-nd-json or any other for simulating streaming client in Apache JMeter for Load test.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go for [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and use [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) for connecting to your WebFlux endpoints and executing the requests, something like:

```
def client = org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
.create('https://your-server-host:your-server-port')

def result = client.get()
.uri('your-endpoint')
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(your-entity.class)

result.subscribe(System.out::println)
```

You can also consider [creating your own plugin for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development)